# apex tabular form icon link column

Tags: forms, oracle-apex, tabular, tabular-form

I am working with a wizard-generated Tabular Form column that needs to display an icon which launches a Javascript function and pass the row value into the function when clicked. The function launches a popUp2 window which sets the values of other fields on that row. So the row number is crucial, but it is always 0 for newly-created rows (in APEX 4.0.0.00.46). I managed to solve that problem by storing the rowNum of new rows into my Updated By column during AddRow.

What I have now is an Updated By column ("Lookup" Heading) which stores the row number of new rows, has onClick="javascript:usePopup(this);" in the Element Attributes which launches the popUp window function, and then gets any values under 2 digits wiped before submit. This fills the correct fields and submits to the table with no problem.

I can't keep using the Updated By column for this function, though. There are currently reports running on this table, so I can't add a new column to the table. I need a dummy column to display the icon, temporarily store the Row Number of newly created rows, and not mess up the MRU. It is f08, so the value of f08_0005 needs to be 0005. I tried making a null column with

```
select
"FUEL_USAGE_DETAIL_ID", ...   
"EXPENSE_TO_PROJECT",   
"EXPENSE_TO_TASK",   
NULL Lookup,   
"UPDATED_BY",   
"PROVIDER"  
from "#OWNER#"."FUEL_USAGE_DETAIL"
```

but that can't submit. I get the Error in mru internal routine: ORA-20001: Error in MRU: row= 1, ORA-20001: ORA-20001: Current version of data in database has changed since user initiated update process. current checksum = "01A949FAF0B3A91914ECACCDC9BBA9E6", item checksum = "B6ADF86455B14EF691B2AFB314926A0D".

Please help me create a null column to display this icon, store the row number of all the rows (including the brand new rows), and not mess up the MRU. If you need pictures of what I have and what I need, see my other thread: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3649771 Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fractal65,
Do not add any null column in tabular form.
just go to>>Edit tabular form attribute make following change
[image]

you will get it position as f02_000X (x-rownum)
now uou can use this rownum value in javascript or anything. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with my last project. Do you have a none displayed row selector? Please try to delete it to see if it will work.

Comment: Thank you, but my row selector is visible, and it is required because users must be able to delete from the tabular form. If I delete it, I must build the delete-by-checkbox functionality back in.

Comment: I read your post on Oracle forum and see what you want to do now. You would need to write a custom MRU process instead of using the the built in APEX's MRU process.

Comment: Thank you, Kiem. How should I make this custom MRU, and what will be different about it?